# Mock ANTD form hook using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to mock `const [form] = Form.useForm();` from ANTD.

```
 const form= jest.mock('antd', () => {
        const originalModule = jest.requireActual('antd');
        return {
            Form: {
                ...originalModule.useForm,
                useForm: () => [{
                    scrollToField: jest.fn(),
                    getFieldInstance: jest.fn()
                }]
            },
        };
    });
```

Running the test using the above code i get

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')
```

Question: Why i get this error and how to fix the test?

Comment: Which line throws this error? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to solve the problem was using a instance of the form to mock it correctly, like this:

```
 jest.mock("antd", () => {
  const antd = jest.requireActual("antd");
  const { Form } = antd;

  const { result } = renderHook(() => Form.useForm());

  return {
    ...antd,
    Form: {
      ...Form,
      useForm: () => [
        {
          ...result.current[0],
          scrollToField: jest.fn(),
          getFieldInstance: jest.fn()
        },
      ],
    },
  };
});
```

Since antd uses the form instance to do operations in their side, it is necessary to mock everything or provide some actual form instance to be used.